# Not able to pass dynamic url Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an url which is `https://www.yahoo.com/**75063**/list.json`.

Here I had ApiClient which has base_url as `https://www.yahoo.com/` and I'm getting the zipcode of location and can be able to append it. But I'm facing problems to append this url to "/list.json."

Also,the above mentioned url is not working one but just included in post to give better understanding of my question.

Comment: can you post your retrofit interface?

Comment: Kindly provide your code that you have written for interface and client class.

Comment: I used @Url annotation and able to solve the problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.